# PYTHON: NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, funções, escopo-de-variáveis

O que tem de errado nesse código pra eu não conseguir chamar a função `pontosNaBorda`?

```
def pontosNaBorda(v0, v1, v2):
    # v0, v1, v2 são coordenadas dos vértices de um triângulo
    return v0

def main():
    alienigenas = []
    n = int(input("Quantidade de alienigenas: "))
    for i in range(0,n):
        alienigenas.append(leAlienigena(i))
        
def leAlienigena(numero_alienigena):
    coordenadas = input("Alienigena %d: " %(numero_alienigena))
    
    # converte a string lida em uma lista de inteiros
    coordenadas = coordenadas.split()
    for i in range(0,6):
        coordenadas[ i ] = int( coordenadas[ i ] )
        
    # separa as três coordenadas dos vértices do alienígena
    v0 = [ coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1] ]
    v1 = [ coordenadas[2], coordenadas[3] ]
    v2 = [ coordenadas[4], coordenadas[5] ]

    return v0, v1, v2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

funcao = int(input("Digite a funcao que deseja testar: "))

if funcao == int(1):
    pontosNaBorda(v0, v1, v2)
```

O erro que dá:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/*/Downloads/EP3
> (Prazo_ 03_07_21)/ep03-rascunho.py", line 32, in <module>
>     pontosNaBorda(v0, v1, v2) NameError: name 'v0' is not defined
> ```

Mas o `v0` não está definido na função `leAlienigena`?

Answer (score 5):

Apesar de você ter comentado na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/516199/112052) que "funcionou", gostaria de deixar uma alternativa - na minha opinião - melhor.

Primeiro, usar variáveis globais - ainda mais da forma que foi feito no seu programa - não me parece uma boa (*spoiler*: geralmente não é, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/925/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50368/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304745/112052)).

Por exemplo, se você ler os dados de 10 alienígenas: ao final do *loop*, as variáveis `v0`, `v1` e `v2` terão apenas os valores do décimo. Ou seja, a função `pontosNaBorda` acaba tendo apenas esses últimos valores. Todos os outros que você leu anteriormente estarão na lista `alienigenas`, é verdade, só que esta lista não está sendo usada para nada, então na verdade o código todo está bem confuso.

Mas antes de arrumar o código, acho melhor você entender um conceito importante: o [escopo de uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13034/112052).

Dentro da função `leAlienigena` você criou as variáveis `v0`, `v1` e `v2` e as retornou, e por isso achou que elas também estariam disponíveis fora da função. Mas na verdade não, pois variáveis criadas dentro de uma função [são locais a esta função](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding): elas só "existem" ali dentro, ninguém de fora consegue acessá-las. Ex:

```py
def funcao():
    x = 1

# executa a função
funcao()
print(x) # NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Veja que depois de executar a função, a variável `x` não está acessível fora dela. Afinal, `x` foi declarado dentro de `funcao` e só existe ali dentro (o escopo desta variável é a função, fora dali ninguém consegue "ver" o `x`).

Ah, mas e se eu retornar o `x`?

```py
def funcao():
    x = 1
    return x # agora eu retorno o x

# Ainda sim dá erro
funcao()
print(x) # NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Mesmo assim dá erro. Afinal, o `return x` só está dizendo "retorne o **valor** da expressão `x`". Ou seja, quem chama a função tem que pegar este valor e fazer algo com ele (atribuir em uma variável, ou usá-lo diretamente em uma outra expressão):

```py
def funcao():
    x = 1
    return x

# executa a função
valor = funcao()
print(valor) # 1
print(x) # NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Veja que eu fiz `valor = funcao()` (a variável `valor` recebe o valor retornado pela `funcao`). Veja que a função retorna o valor que `x` tinha no momento em que ela foi executada. Esse valor (que no caso é `1`) foi retornado e colocado na variável `valor`. Mas depois que a função terminou de executar, a variável `x` "some" (pois sendo local à função, ela só existe ali dentro, e quando a função termina de executar, todas as variáveis locais deixam de existir). Essa é uma distinção importante, pois **o que é retornado é o valor, não a variável** ([leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/112052) para mais detalhes). Veja que o `x` continua não existindo fora da função, e qualquer tentativa de acessá-lo dará erro.

É por isso que `v0`, `v1` e `v2` não estão disponíveis fora da função `leAlienigenas`, e ao tentar passá-las para `pontosNaBorda`, deu o `NameError`.

Aliás, o mesmo acontece com a lista `alienigenas`, que só existe na função `main`. Depois que esta função termina, você não usa esta lista para mais nada (nem sequer retorna), então ela deixa de existir. Ou seja, você lê um monte de dados e depois eles somem (e usando variáveis globais, você só tem o último valor digitado, perdendo todos os outros que estavam guardados na lista). Por isso achei estranho que tenha "funcionado", eu revisaria tudo antes de ter essa certeza (pode ser que o código não esteja completo e "faça sentido", mas só com o que tem na pergunta, ficou bem esquisito).

---

#### Arrumando o código

Sendo assim, uma alternativa melhor seria usar o retorno das funções, atribuindo-os em variáveis e/ou passando esses valores para as outras funções.

Para começar, o programa lê as coordenadas de um **ou mais** alienígenas, guardando-as em uma lista. Mas como já dito, essa lista não é usada para nada, então uma sugestão seria retorná-la:

```py
def main():
    n = int(input("Quantidade de alienigenas: "))
    alienigenas = []
    for i in range(n):
        alienigenas.append(leAlienigena(i))
    return alienigenas # retorne a lista de alienígenas
```

E a leitura pode ser simplificada (levando em conta que não é feita validação dos dados, como por exemplo, se foi realmente digitado 6 números):

```py
def leAlienigena(numero_alienigena):
    # converte a string lida em uma lista de inteiros
    coordenadas = list(map(int, input(f"Alienigena {numero_alienigena}: ").split()))

    # separa as três coordenadas dos vértices do alienígena
    v0 = coordenadas[0:2]
    v1 = coordenadas[2:4]
    v2 = coordenadas[4:6]
    return v0, v1, v2
```

E ao executar o programa, você pega a lista de alinígenas retornada por `main`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pega os valores retornados
    alienigenas = main()
```

Mas só um detalhe: esta lista contém uma ou mais tuplas, sendo que cada tupla contém 3 listas contendo as coordenadas de um alienígena. E como `pontosNaBorda` recebe essas 3 coordenadas separadamente, você teria que passá-las uma vez para cada alienígena. Algo assim:

```py
for v0, v1, v2 in alienigenas: # para cada alienígena, pegar as coordenadas
    pontosNaBorda(v0, v1, v2)
```

Ou, se quiser de um alienígena específico:

```py
v0, v1, v2 = alienigenas[0] # pega as coordenadas do primeiro alienígena
pontosNaBorda(v0, v1, v2)
```

Se bem que não ficou claro o que é para fazer (mas se você leu os dados de vários alienígenas e guardou em uma lista, me parece fazer sentido analisar as coordenadas de todos, mas aí é com você: agora que você tem a lista com tudo que foi digitado, fica mais simples decidir o que fazer).

Ou seja, o código completo ficaria:

```py
def pontosNaBorda(v0, v1, v2):
    return v0

def main():
    n = int(input("Quantidade de alienigenas: "))
    alienigenas = []
    for i in range(n):
        alienigenas.append(leAlienigena(i))
    return alienigenas # retorne a lista de alienígenas

def leAlienigena(numero_alienigena):
    # converte a string lida em uma lista de inteiros
    coordenadas = list(map(int, input(f"Alienigena {numero_alienigena}: ").split()))

    # separa as três coordenadas dos vértices do alienígena
    v0 = coordenadas[0:2]
    v1 = coordenadas[2:4]
    v2 = coordenadas[4:6]
    return v0, v1, v2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # pega os valores retornados
    alienigenas = main()
    print(alienigenas)
    funcao = int(input("Digite a funcao que deseja testar: "))
    if funcao == 1: # assim, os valores estarão disponíveis aqui
        v0, v1, v2 = alienigenas[0] # pega as coordenadas do primeiro alienígena
        pontosNaBorda(v0, v1, v2)
```

É importante notar que as variáveis `v0`, `v1` e `v2` que foram criadas dentro do `if` **não** são as mesmas que estão dentro da função `leAlienigena`. Elas por acaso têm o mesmo nome, mas lembre-se do escopo: as que estão dentro da função são locais e só existem ali dentro. Seria o mesmo que ter isso:

```py
def funcao():
    x = 1
    return x

x = 2
funcao()
print(x) # 2
```

Este código imprime "2", pois o `x` que está dentro da função é diferente do `x` que está fora. Uma não interfere na outra.

Esta distinção é importante para organizar o código e deixar a função mais "auto-contida". A cada chamada de `leAlienigena`, ela está lidando com os dados de um único alienígena. Deixar as variáveis globais faz com que a semântica se misture: não existem mais os dados do alienígena atual, e sim "os dados", uma única instância deles. E ao chamar a função `pontosNaBorda`, ela receberá apenas os dados do último alienígena lido. Mas se essa era a intenção, então para que ler dados de vários alienígenas, se no fim só o último será usado? (é por isso que eu disse que o código está estranho, e mais estranho ainda que o uso de `global` tenha "resolvido" o problema - pode ter resolvido o `NameError`, mas desconfio que a lógica ainda está esquisita e provavelmente errada).